# Quiero crear un botón que muestre los números de teléfono que ya se muestran en una tabla

Tags: php, sql

Estoy buscando una manera sencilla de que al realizar click en el botón AVISO, este muestre en un mensaje tipo echo el numero de teléfono que se encuentra en el mismo registro de dicha tabla.

Envio parte del codigo que corresponde con esa tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
introducir el código aquí
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
  <?php
    $telefono=$_POST['id'];
     echo "El número seleccionado es:   $telefono";
    $users->rowsToTableWizardSelect('users', $users->getUsersWizard($_POST['quantity'], true));  
      ?>
```

Comment: Ese es todo el codigo que tienes?¿ Muestranos tu codigo completo para saber que metodo estas usando para resolver el problema por favor. Solo estas usando POST con HTML y PHP o tambien has incluido JS o Python?¿ No veo la etiqueta con 'id'

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.